# Listview and custom dataprovider search yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am working on a project in which to display some data i am using a custom query and saving those data in dataProvider. Passing that dataProvider to view file and displaying using a `Listview`. just like below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left search-form" action="">
        <div class="form-group"><input type="text" class="form-control app-search" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
    </form>
</nav>

<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<?= \yii\widgets\ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => 'eventlistview',
    'layout' => "{items}",
]); ?>

</div>
```

I want to implement a `search` bar for that `Listview`. I am not using any `SearchModel` so i am confused that how can i do that?

Here is my `action` code.

```
public function actionEvent()
{
    $this->layout = 'app';
    if(isset($_GET['latitude']) && isset($_GET['longitude'])){
            $query = new Query();
            $query  ->select(['e.*','COUNT(d.event_id) as checkins' ,'o.clubname',new Expression("case when c.id is not null then 1 else 0 end is_checkedin")])
                ->from('event e')
                ->innerJoin('organiser o', 'e.organiser_id = o.organiser_id')
                ->leftJoin('checkin c', 'c.event_id = e.id and c.user_id ='.$_GET['user_id'])
                ->leftJoin('checkin d', 'd.event_id = e.id' )
                ->where('e.interest_id IN
                             ( SELECT area_intrest.id FROM area_intrest, user WHERE FIND_IN_SET(area_intrest.id,user.area_intrest) AND user.id='.$_GET['user_id'].')')
                ->groupBy('e.id');

            $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => $query,

            ]);
        }

  return $this->render('event' ,['dataProvider' => $dataProvider]);
}
```

I am just confused because i am not using any search model here so i dont know how can i search using `title` of the `event`.

Comment: Two things... 1) show all the related action code ....2 ) How do you perform the query request for filter from your view?

Comment: @scaisEdge  thats all the action code there is. and i get the required data from url using `GET`. I dont use any filter. I can add the code of the layout i am using `eventlistview`,but i dont know how that will help solve my problem.

Comment: could you explain what are $ _ GET ['latitude'] and $ _ GET ['longitude'] and where they come in ?... because they view it in the query do not see any reference to these fields

Comment: @scaisEdge that comes from URL and its based on location of the user.

Comment: In your search bar what kind of value the user input for perform the search ? ... what filter do you want create?

Comment: @scaisEdge just using the `title` of the event.

Answer (score 1):

In view you  can use an active form  for sending the value

```
<?php 
      $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'my-form', 
          'method'=>'get',
          'action' => Url::to('your-controller/event')]); 
?>
      <input type="text" class="form-control app-search" name="my_search" placeholder="Search">
<?= Html::submitButton('search') ?>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

in your actionEvent you can

```
$this->layout = 'app';
if (isset($_GET('my_search')) {
   // perform what you nedd ..
}
if(isset($_GET['latitude']) && isset($_GET['longitude'])){
```